# How do I submit form values with Xui framework's xhr object?

Tags: ajax, javascript-framework, xui

I'm giving the Xui javascript framework for mobile apps a spin and I'm stuck on form submission using its xhr ajax object. I'm trying to submit username and password form values to a php script. This is my code:

```
x$(window).load(function(){ 

    x$('#login').click(function(){
    var data = {};
    x$('#xuiForm input').each(function(elem){
        data[elem.name] = elem.value;
    });
    var forminput = JSON.stringify(data);

    x$('#xuiForm').xhr('http://localhost/demo/getform.php',{
        method:'post',
        async: 'false',
        data: forminput,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        callback: function(){x$('#responsediv').html('inner',this.responseText);}
        })
    });
});
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit your form with a `form-urlencoded` content type, you should not use `JSON.stringify()` but create a url-encoded string instead. Example:

```
var data = "";
replyForm.find('#xuiForm input').each(function(elem){
    data += elem.name + "=" +  encodeURIComponent(elem.value) + "&";
});
```